# Does preparing your pouch when fighting bosses the first time help with the Boss Challenge?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I am playing through *Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* a second time after having beaten it on Normal Mode. The first time I played, I had difficulty with the Thunder Dragon's Boss Challenge. I'm looking for ways to make the challenge easier in Hero Mode, especially since it will be more difficult than before due to the very nature of Hero Mode.

I remember last time I played the Thunder Dragon's Boss Challenge that there was a limitation where I could not bring in items to a Boss Fight replay which I did not have when I fought that boss originally. For example, no using the bow on bosses early in the game.

Because of this rule, I am trying a strategy of placing as many items in my pouch prior to fighting each boss *the first time* which I feel might be helpful during the Thunder Dragon's challenge on *subsequent fights*. For example, when fighting Scaldera (the ball of molten rock in the Earth temple) I brought 4 large bomb bags so I could carry a metric ton of bombs.

Does this mean that when I fight Scaldera in the Thunder Dragon's Boss Challenge I will be able to carry 65 bombs even if I am only carrying a single bomb bag when I talk to the Thunder Dragon?

If so, what should I equip before each boss to get the maximum benefit when replaying those bosses? For example, I will want a few extra quivers before fighting the Sandship's boss!

Answer (score 1):

If the game saved your pouch status from the original boss fight, you would be forced to use whatever shield you had equipped at the time. This is clearly not the case. Therefore, I posit that your pouch status during the boss rush depends solely on what you have when you initiate the game and not at all based on what you had back then.

Comment: I thought the Thunder Dragon said the exception was that he would let you carry your current shield, but the rest of your pouch would remain as it was from the original fight? I can't recall now.

Comment: He says that the *items* you can use are restricted to the time of the fight, but that *pouch items* are "prohibited".